# Intellisense not working with F# script files

Tags: f#, intellisense, f#-interactive, f#-scripting

I'm using VS2008 SP1 and the August 2010 CTP for F# 2.0.0.0. Intellisense works for standard F# files (.fs) but not for script files (.fsx). As far as I can understand from articles I've found, it should work in both cases.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the F# CTP but that didn't help. Any ideas what might have gone wrong?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I can confirm that this DOES work for me, on Visual Studio 2008 9.0.21022.8 RTM, August 2010 CTP for F# 2.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

One more try is that you can refer to .NET 4.0 assemblies instead of the "Client Profile" that visual studio 2010 creates by default for you. This is one annoyance you get with Client profile projects in F#.